# Sitemap Mysql PHP dividido em quantidades de resultado

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>';
echo'   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9     http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

include 'conexao.php';
include 'acoes.php';

$sql = mysql_query("select nome, nota from aluno");

while ($string = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){?>
            <url>
                <loc>http://www.escola.com.br/<?echo     removerosAcentos($string['nome']);?>/<?echo $string['nota'];?></loc>
                <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
            </url>
<?php } ?> 
</urlset>
```

Este código gera um sitemap (puxando do banco de dados)

Eu preciso gerar um sitemap com 45 mil (sitemap1.xml) e depois que atingir os 45 mil resultados um outro sitemap (sitemap2.xml) e assim por diante.

Existe uma coluna com o nome "numero" (Ex: 054322123) que pode ser usado para ordenar. Eu não tenho noção de como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar, de forma detalhada? Agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você rodar um contador ja não resolve?

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';
include 'acoes.php';

$sql = mysql_query("select nome, nota from aluno");

$a = 0;
while ($string = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if ($a == 0)
    {
        $data = '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9     http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
        $data .= '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>';
        $data .= '<urlset>';
    }

    $data .= '<url>';
    $data .= '<loc>http://www.escola.com.br/' . removerosAcentos($string['nome']);
    $data .= $string['nota'] . '</loc>';
    $data .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
    $data .= '</url>';
    $a += 1;
    if ($a == 45.000)
    {
        $data .= '</urlset>';
        $a = 0;

        $nome_arquivo = uniqid();
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $nome_arquivo . '.xml"');
        header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
        readfile($nome_arquivo . '.xml');
 // Os dados do arquivo estão presos na variável $data, basta usar os dados dela pra inserir as informações na XML
//Aqui você faz a saída individual pra cada arquivo de 45.000 registros
    }
}
?>
```

Deste jeito que está agora, a cada 45.00 linhas será gerado um novo id para nomear um arquivo novo, mas voce vai precisar estudar como gerar essa xml individual com PHP, você pode usar várias classes, acredito que XMLWritter é a mais fácil.

Comment: AnthraxisBR, Como ficaria no meu código acima (Eu realmente não tenho muita noção) E como seria criado os arquivos automaticamente? sitemap1.xml sitemap2.xml etc? Consegue detalhar mais? Obrigado.

Comment: Da um olhada na atualização da resposta, agora você deve conseguir fazer isso

Comment: Estou tentando montar em cima do seu código. Até agora nada, caso consiga posto aqui a solução! valeu!